# How to substitute string in a text file with a couple of numbers in a list using python?

Tags: python, list, file, input, output

The example is that there is a list lst=[2,4,6,8,10] and a text file which contains 'h = 1', I would like to change 1 into the numbers in lst, and keep the rest of that text remains the same, saving in separate text files automatically. I wrote a dumb one using .replace('h=1','h=2').... But it won't work when it comes to a large amount since I have to edit it manually. How could I realize the function given by a random input list, the text file could be substituted with the value in the list?

Comment: I suggest you to write your code clearly, and try to rephrase the question in concise and clear manner.

Comment: @KshitijMittal Basically I have a text file with a line "h = 1", I need a code that can read a list of numbers, and substitute each item with 1,(h is the variables) , and then create bunch of new files with h equals to different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use str.format() . `{}` is a wildcard in your string. `'{} is the number {}'.format('one', 1)` returns the string `'one is the number 1'`

```
file_name = 'the_file_{}.txt'
my_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for num in my_list:
    new_file = open(file_name.format(num), 'w')
    new_text = big_text_string.replace('h=1', 'h={}'.format(num))
    new_file.write(new_text)
    new_file.close()
```

you could write a function that takes the list as a variable.